# Excel で16進数の表示や計算を行いたい

Tags: excel

Excelでセルにアドレスを直接16進数で入力し、加減算して結果をそのまま16進数で表示することはできますか？

Comment: 「アドレス」とは何のことを指してらっしゃいますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HEX2DECでいったん１０進数に変換し、計算、その後DEC2HEXで元に戻すことになると思います。